# How to log CPU instructions executed by program with x64dbg?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly

How to log CPU instructions executed by program with x64dbg?

I saw https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18634/x64dbg-see-the-current-position question, but I can't find the way to log instructions.

Comment: Other ways to do this include Intel SDE (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator) / PIN ([Log all instruction with intel pintool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51478420)), or with HW support from CPUs with Intel PT: [How to run record instruction-history and function-call-history in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22507169).  Or with GDB, just scripted single-stepping (vastly slower) [Tracing/profiling instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2971926)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand - you want to log all the executed instructions. The easiest would be to log them in the file. To do this you need to:

1. Pause the program, either via `Pause` option (F12) or using breakpoints
2. Select `Trace` menu and then `Trace into...` (Ctrl+Alt+F7) or `Trace over...` (Ctrl+Alt+F8). If you want to log every instruction you probably want to use `Trace into...`
3. Now in the newly created window
   [image: Trace dialog]

you can select the `Log Text` format, you can use the proposed `0x{p:cip} {i:cip}` which will log the data to file like `0x006E8749 mov ebp, esp`. It is also good idea to set the `Maximum trace count` and the `Log File...` where the data will be stored. After you are done just press `OK` and the x64dbg will start executing your program and log all the instructions. Keep in mind that the program won't work really fast during the trace procedure.